# Nativescript - How to use nsRouterLink programmatically in .ts code

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

In nativescript 5.0 I know how to use [nsRouterLink] in .html

But I would like to use similar functionality in .ts file.

Is it possible to redirect user and pass parameters?

Possibly without using page & frame object.

Comment: marc_s, thank for the edit!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RouterExtensions`

```
@Component({
  // ...
})
export class MainComponent {
   constructor(private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions) {
    // ...
   } 
}
```

Refer [official docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/angular-navigation#clearing-page-navigation-history) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(private router:RouterExtensions)
```

set this in constructor

```
this.router.navigate(['**/test**'])
```

pass the route like test